# Cannot create multiple many to many relations in pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table

I'm trying to create an App in Laravel 5 which tracks medical exams for patients so i can create a patient history, i'm using Eloquent as my model abstraction recommendation.

I have created three tables and a pivot one for this purpose using laravel migration, those are shown in the diagram below:
[image]

Users can be either Doctors or Administrators, they enter the Patient's score results for an specific Exam they make, for instance I have a pivot table which include three foreign keys to relate the three entities:

- exam_id
- patient_id
- user_id

In Eloquent I made these Many to many Models following Laravel Documentation [Many To Many](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) to support the proposed business logic:

```
<?php
    // Patient.php
    class Patient extends Model
    {
        public function exams() {

            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Exam', 'exam_patient');
        }
    }

    // Exam.php
    class Exam extends Model
    {
        public function patients()
        {

            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Patient', 'exam_patient');
        }

        public function users()
        {

            return $this->belongstoMany('App\User', 'exam_patient');
        }
    }

    // User.php
    class User extends Model
    {
        public function exams() {

            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Exam', 'exam_patient');
        }
    }
```

In tinker I try to simulate a common use case before doing major changes: A Doctor makes an exam to a Patient:

```
 >>> $user= App\User::first()
=> App\User {#671
     id: "1",
     name: "Victor",
     email: "",
     created_at: "2015-10-10 18:33:54",
     updated_at: "2015-10-10 18:33:54",
   }

>>> $patient= App\Patient::first()
=> App\Patient {#669
     id: "1",
     username: "",
     name: "Tony",
     lastname: "",
     birthday: "0000-00-00",
     created_at: "2015-10-10 18:32:56",
     updated_at: "2015-10-10 18:32:56",
   }

>>> $exam= App\Exam::first()
=> App\Exam {#680
     id: "1",
     name: "das28",
     title: "Das28",
     created_at: "2015-10-10 18:31:31",
     updated_at: "2015-10-10 18:31:31",
   }

>>> $user->save()
=> true
>>> $patient->save()
=> true
>>> $exam->save()
=> true
```

The problem is when I try to link (or attach) at least two models I get the following error:

```
   >>> $patient->exams()->attach(1) 
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message
    'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a
    child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cliniapp`.`exam_patient`, CONSTRAINT
    `exam_patient_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `exam_patient` (`exam_id`, `patient_id`)
    values (1, 1))'
```

How can I link the three models if I can't even attach two of them? Is there any way in tinker to mass attach them so i can relate them in my pivot table (exam_patient) and MySql doesn't show that error OR if I'm mistaken in my approach? Any help it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When there are extra fields on your [Many to Many](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationships, you have to "register" them when you declare the relationship, as seen in the *Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns* section of the above link.

So you should always declare your "extra" pivot tables, which are different depending on where you are defining the relationship:

```
class Patient extends Model
{
    public function exams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Exam', 'exam_patient')->withPivot('user_id');
    }
}

class Exam extends Model
{
    public function patients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Patient', 'exam_patient')->withPivot('user_id');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongstoMany('App\User', 'exam_patient')->withPivot('patient_id');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function exams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Exam', 'exam_patient')->withPivot('patient_id');
    }
}
```

In the *Attaching / Detaching* section, you can see that you can set those extra fields like so:

```
$patient->exams()->attach($exam->id, ['user_id' => $user->id]);
```

Your problem was that the user_id Foreign Key constraint on your exam_patient table was failing when you where creating the patient/exam relationship without passing data for the user_id column, so the above will work.

If you don't want to always pass the user_id like that for whatever reason, you could also make that user_id column nullable on the database.

Of course, it can be argued that using two pivot tables (exam_patient and exam_user), or using many-to-many **polymorphic** relationships would be a better approach here.

---

As we can see from the [Laravel docs on polymorphic relations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations), to implement them here we'd drop the exam_patient table for an *examable* table, which would have 3 columns: exam_id, examable_id and examable_type.

The Models would look like:

```
class Patient extends Model
{
    public function exams()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Exam', 'examable');
    }
}

class Exam extends Model
{
    public function patients()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Patient', 'examable');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\User', 'examable');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function exams()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Exam', 'examable');
    }
}
```

To update the examable table fully, you'd do something like:

```
$exam->patients()->save($patient);
$exam->users()->save($user);
```

So it's two queries instead of one, you lose the foreign key relationships and "examables" is an awkward name.

The argument for would be that the relationships are a bit more declarative and it's easier to handle a single exam for a single patient belonging to multiple users/doctors.

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Johnny, i'll try it tomorrow. You catched my attention proposing a different approach which would be a polymorphic relationship, how would it be in my case? Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem @tblancog, I've added relevant docs and a simple implementation of the polymorphic relationships for your case.

Comment: It worked like a charm @Johnny, i decided to take your initial approach as the solution and it worked.